# Flutter, dart. My MainModel class is inheriting from Model of the scoped_model package with 4 other class.

Tags: flutter

Was working at first but after I did some flutter upgrades it gives an error message.
 My current flutter version, 0.10.2

class MainModel extends Model with ConnectedProductsModel, UserModel, ProductsModel, UtilityModel { }  error message: "The class 'UserModel' can't be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than Object."

Answer (score 9):

You need to change something on your code.

Open your ConnectedProductsModel.dart file and change

```
class ConnectedProductsModel extends Model
class ProductsModel extends ConnectedProductsModel
class UserModel extends ConnectedProductsModel
class UtilityModel extends ConnectedProductsModel
```

to

```
mixin ConnectedProductsModel on Model
mixin ProductsModel on ConnectedProductsModel
mixin UserModel on ConnectedProductsModel
mixin UtilityModel on ConnectedProductsModel
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. But I don't understand the mixin, could u please explain it to me

Comment: I found an explanation at the dart language forum:  [dart forum](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/MHlPCgoIZfk)

Answer (score 2):

open a file named analysis_options.yaml in root folder and then put these lines code into that file, then restart your IDE

```
# https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  errors:
    mixin_inherits_from_not_object: ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

Include this code in your “pubspec.yaml” file at the very end:

```
analyzer:
strong-mode: true
language:
enableSuperMixins: true
```

Comment: with indention or not?